# "Open in Integrated Terminal" in vscode in current integrated terminal, not a new one

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

In vscode, right-clicking in the explorer on a file (or folder) and selecting "Open in Integrated Terminal" will create a new integrated terminal at the path of that directory.

Is there a way to open that directory in the currently open integrated terminal? Ideally without having to copy the path and type "cd " and paste the path.

I feel like I'm missing something.

If not, are there any extensions that do this? Using macOS.

**What I've Tried**

- I've searched for and could not find a way to do this.
- I use the vscode extension "Terminal Sync", but you must have a file open in the editor and the file must be the current one being used in order to cd into that file's directory in the integrated terminal